# Java change and move non-standard XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, parsing

I am using a third party application and would like to change one of its files. The file is stored in XML but with an invalid doctype.

When I try to read use a it errors out becuase the doctype contains "file:///ReportWiz.dtd"
(as shown, with quotes) and I get an exception for cannot find file. Is there a way to tell the docbuilder to ignore this? I have tried setValidate to false and setNamespaceAware to false for the DocumentBuilderFactory.

The only solutions I can think of are

- copy file line by line into a new file, omitting the offending line, doing what i need to do, then copying into another new file and inserting the offending line back in, or
- doing mostly the same above but working with a FileStream of some sort (though I am not clear on how I could do this..help?)

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
docFactory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell your DocumentBuilderFactory to ignore the DTD declaration like this:

```
docFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

See [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html) for a list of available features.

You also might find JDOM a lot easier to work with than org.w3c.dom:

```
org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
org.jdom.Document doc = builder.build(file);
```

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed. THANKS!! Welcom to SO.

Answer (score 2):

Handle resolution of the DTD manually, either by returning a copy of the DTD file (loaded from the classpath) or by returning an empty one. You can do this by setting an entity resolver on your document builder:

```
    EntityResolver er = new EntityResolver() {
        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                throws SAXException, IOException {
            if ("file:///ReportWiz.dtd".equals(systemId)) {
                System.out.println(systemId);
                InputStream zeroData = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
                return new InputSource(zeroData);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: More complex then I needed. I didnt try this but I was really only looking for a way to ignore it completely.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was dealing with it as a stream.  You could make a new adapter at some level and just copy input to output except for the offending text.

If the file is shortish (under half a gig or so) you could also read the entire thing into a byte array and make your modifications there, then create a new stream from the byte array into your builder.

That's the advantage of the amazingly bulky way Java handles streams, you actually have a lot of flexibility.

Comment: could you maybe help me with some example code(or a link), this sounds a lot like what I want to do.

Comment: Looks like what you want to do is subclass FilterInputStream and overwrite read().  When your read is called, call super.read() to get the data, scan & modify the data, and return it.  I'll fool around with it if I get some time, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Here is an example that has very simple filtering (it excludes unprintable characters from the stream I believe).  http://www.cafeaulait.org/slides/sd2000west/javaio/44.html  Your case is harder because you need to recognize a multi-character pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I was debating was storing all of the file in a string, then doing my manipulations and wiring the String out to a file.None of these seem clean or easy, but what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to assume the parser is xerces, and want generic solution see [this](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/putoff_dtd_parsing_html)