# Java DOM messing with my XML headers and adding attributes on its own

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm having an issue with a small program that I wrote. It does what I intended it to do (add/remove/modify attributes) very well - I'm super excited about that part. But when I output the file, my headers change and some elements have attributes added to them automatically.

Here's what I start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "teilite-ur.dtd">
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
...
<availability>
...
```

After transforming each element node to contain an additional attribute(name=test,value=working), here's what I end up with:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" test="working">
    <teiHeader test="working" type="text">
        <fileDesc test="working">
...
<availability default="false" status="unknown" test="working">
...
```

So, short overview:

- !DOCTYPE line was removed
- xmlns:xsi... was added
- type="text", default="false", status="unknown" anchored="true" attributes are added automatically (there may be others, but those are the ones that popped out at me).

I read in here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133395/remove-xml-declaration-from-the-generated-xml-document-using-java] how to prevent the XML declaration from being added to the top. But, I'm not sure how to disable the rest of the additions.

Thanks!

Here's some self-contained code that does basically what I want it to (little more customization in the real program, but that shouldn't be relevant) and the relevant [IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) that I used to help build it:

```
package xml_attrib_test;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Input
        File whichFile = new File("C:\\Users\\mw2xx\\Desktop\\proceedings.vol1.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory;
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc;
        XPathFactory factory;
        XPath xpath;
        XPathExpression expr;
        NodeList nodes;

        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setSchema(null);
            domFactory.setValidating(false);
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            domFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(whichFile);

            factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            xpath = factory.newXPath();
            expr = xpath.compile("//*");

            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            nodes = (NodeList) result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in parser.");
            return;
        }

        // Do Stuff With the XML Doc

        String attributeTag = "test";
        String attrValue = "working";

        for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Node n = nodes.item(j);

            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element e = (Element) n;
                e.setAttribute(attributeTag, attrValue);
            } else if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
                Attr a = (Attr) n;
                if (a.getName().equals(attributeTag)) {
                    a.setValue(attrValue);
                }
            }
        }

        // Output
        TransformerFactory tFactory;
        Transformer transformer;
        DOMSource source;
        File resultFile;
        StreamResult result;

        try {
            tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

            source = new DOMSource(doc);
            resultFile = new File("$$$$$.tmp");
            result = new StreamResult(resultFile);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in transformer.");
            return;
        }

        whichFile.delete();
        resultFile.renameTo(whichFile);

        System.out.println("Success!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more days of googling and searching stack overflow I found a similar question which provided the setting I needed.

```
domFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

[Java change and move non-standard XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358048/java-change-and-move-non-standard-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the standard JDK DOM parser?

If yes, then I'm guessing that you're using a schema for validation, and that schema specifies default attribute values. This would explain:

- Removing the DOCTYPE, because it's not used with schema validation. You could try calling `setValidating(true)`, but then you'll probably need to add an `EntityResolver`
- Setting default values as described in the XSD, and inserting attributes that support schema validation.

The answer, if all you care about is updating the XML, is to avoid the schema. Or parse once with the schema to validate, then once again to update.

Comment: If this answer doesn't help you, please post the code that you're using (or better, a small, self-contained example that shows the problem)

Comment: I posted the code in the question - your answer makes logical sense to me, but I thought I already disabled schema/validation (see the domFactory.set[X] lines). I'm guessing that I'm just misunderstanding the settings that I flipped.

Comment: @MetricMike - looking at the code you posted, I can't see any reason for it to do what you're claiming. However, it looks like this code is extracted from a larger program, one that runs in a GUI. Have you tried putting this code into its own `main` and testing it?

Comment: I am using Buoy, which is a library built on top of Swing - but when I pulled my code out into its own project and tested it, I still ran into the same issues. I updated the code in my question to reflect the "test" code I ran (and the XML snippets at the top more accurately portray what goes into and out of that code). Also, thanks for continuing to help me out with this!

Comment: It doesn't require schemas -- the parser will fill in default attributes from the DTD.